# I am using mac notebook pro, and i installed ride when i try to create test case i am not seeing grid in the test case

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am using mac notebook pro, i installed python 3.8,robotframework-seleniumlibrary==6.0.0,wxPython==4.1.1 and robotframework-ride-1.7.4.2 and in project folder and test suite i added SeleniumLibrary.

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 0):

Like I mention on the RIDE project [README](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE#readme), to run with Python 3.8 you need to install the pre-release version (2.0b1).
However it is better to install current development version, as mentioned in that document (please use with care because there are some bugs).

Comment: Sure Helio Thanks for your suggestion